# hide specific css and js files in specific page wordpress with id or without?

Tags: css, javascript

Hi guys i have google and searched and tested codes i finded here but nothing works, i have wordpress site and i want to make some css and js dont load in the first page because some plugins puts the css and js in the first page but i dont need it here...

For example:
`<link rel='stylesheet' id='cleaning-services-shop-css' href='/wp-content/themes/stadperfekt/css/shop.css' type='text/css' media='all' />`

i dont need it in first page so i want it not to load only in first page...

If somebody knows it will be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're not wanting something to load on the front page, wrap it in a `!is_front_page()` check. `!is_front_page()` will check if the current page is your site's base URL (regardless of whether you have it set to a static page or the posts page in your settings).

Example:

```php
<?php
if ( !is_front_page() ) : ?>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<?php
endif; ?>
```

Please remember not to directly edit plugin/theme files, they will get overwritten whenever they get updated and all your work will be gone. For themes, create a child theme instead, and for plugins you'll need to check their documentation to see if they have a hook/filter to remove their css/js links.

Source: [WordPress Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/)

Comment: Hi. thanks for trying to help me, but i think the code you wrote will show that css in front page, that style.css already showing on all pages, but i want to by code make it not load on first page..? If you understand me :/

Comment: No, that code will hide it on the front page and should work fine. The `!` means `not`.  I might try using a wp_enqueue though instead.

Comment: the problem is the css already runig true i dont know wich file in wordpress, where should i put the code then? if i put it on header nothing happens, i want to hide the css already runig thrue some file.. is it possible?

Comment: if you look in functions: code: wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', CLEANING_SERVICES_JS_URL . '/vendor/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true); how to disable it on only front page. or style: wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', CLEANING_SERVICES_CSS_URL . '/vendor/bootstrap.min.css', '', null);

Comment: @MilanAndjelkovic Yes you wrap the code you want to hide on the front page with the `!is_front_page()` if statement. If you've already found the `wp_enqueue_script()` function that enqueues the file, you can wrap that statement with `!is_front_page()` instead.

Comment: im so sorry im so new at this, how can i write the code if my code already looks like this: wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', CLEANING_SERVICES_CSS_URL . '/vendor/bootstrap.min.css', '', null); so it hides this from functions.php only in front page!

Comment: `if( !is_front_page() ) { wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', CLEANING_SERVICES_CSS_URL . '/vendor/bootstrap.min.css', '', null); }`

Comment: im very glad that you trying to help me, but if i delete one of those in functions or something still the css load in viewed soruce in front page, is there som other file mabye this css are put into then functions.php im sorry for disturbing you!

Comment: @MilanAndjelkovic That's going to highly depend on your theme/plugin configuration so that's not something I can help you with. Check though to see if you're using a caching plugin and purge the cache from it, or clear your browser's cache to see if that fixes it. Some CSS files get cached and the changes won't show up on a refresh of the page.